# Friendlist in AIO challenge

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working on the problem at http://orac.amt.edu.au/cgi-bin/train/problem.pl?set=simple3&problemid=416. Below is the code which I came up. Sample data executed successfully but when I submit the code I am able to execute only 71% of the test cases. Not sure where went wrong. Please guide me.

Briefly the problem is as below:
I am trying to get the max friend list from the friend linking.

1 2

2 3

3 7

1 8

1 9

Output is 1 as it has more friend list
If the friend list match with max the list all.

1 2

2 3

3 7

1 8

9 10

Output should be. 1 2 3 as they have equal number of friends.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    freopen("listin.txt","r",stdin);
    freopen("listout.txt","w",stdout);
    int f=0, a= 0, b= 0, m = 1;
    long size = 1001;

    cin >> f;
    int arr[size] = {};
    int x[size] = {};
    for(int i = 0; i < f; i++){
        cin >> a >> b;
        arr[a] += 1;
        arr[b] += 1;
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
        if(m < arr[j]){
            m = arr[j];
        }
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
        if(m == arr[j]){
            x[j] = j;
        }
    }
    for(int k = 0; k < size; k++){
        if(x[k] > 0)
            cout << x[k] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of linking to the requisites, explain them in your question.

Comment: Thanks Brian I added and updated the question

Comment: You mention that in the second case output should be `1 2 3`, so what is your program outputting instead?

Comment: My program executes perfectly on these test cases which I have provided but when I submit it for the Online judge it only executes 71 % of the test cases. I am not sure which case I am missing in this requirement.

Comment: using python the problem resolved in the below link. 
     https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/173268/aio-programming-challenge-friendlist-who-has-the-most-friends/173389#173389    I am not sure which edge case I was able to not guess in C++ coding.